# Spark UDF to compare dates

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can i do date comparison in a spark UDF using `java.sql.Date`.

something like below ..

```
def optimisedTDate =
    udf(
      (bdate: Date, tdate: Date, pdate: Date, fcdate: Date) =>
        if (tdate == null && pdate == null) fcdate
        else if (tdate > bdate) tdate
        else bdate
    )

val processed_df = base_df.withColumn(
      "final_date",
      optimisedTDate(lit {
        Date.valueOf("2010-01-01")
      },
        col("tdate"),
        col("pdate"),
        col("fcdate")))
```

Comment: can't you use inbuilt functions for these instead of udf?

Comment: actually there are lot of comparisons to be done, hence I thought to create an UDF. the one showed in question is a very basic  and not the complete comparison logic

Comment: You'd rather use when/otherwise instead.

Comment: Definitely go for built-in functions over UDFs whenever you can, they take full advantage of the knowledge of the data layout and save you a lot of time in serialization/deserialization that UDFs just need to do. `$"date1".between($"date2", $"date3")` is also far more readable IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I got it working using built-in functions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by others, use Spark's built-in functions whenever possible for better performance.  If you must go for a `udf`, you can use an `implicit conversion` to enable date/time comparison:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import java.sql.Date

val d1 = Date.valueOf("2018-06-11")
val d2 = Date.valueOf("2018-06-12")

implicit def dateToDT(d: Date) = new DateTime(d)

d1.isAfter(d2)
// res1: Boolean = false

d1.isBefore(d2)
// res2: Boolean = true
```

In case you prefer using inequality operators, use the following instead:

```
implicit def dateToDT(d: Date) = (new DateTime(d)).getMillis

d1 > d2
// res3: Boolean = false

d1 < d2
// res4: Boolean = true
```